# I am unable to do form validation for separate widgets, how to do form validation for divided widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have separated form widgets into separate files And now I am trying to validate form but not working

When I combined all widgets into 1, form validation working

How to do form validation for separate widgets

these are the following code I have done in separate files

```
class _OnBoardFormState extends State<OnBoardForm> {
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
  child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: const [
        //Selection dropdown for first and Last Name

        OnBoardFormName(),
        SizedBox(height: 15),

        //Selection dropdown for Email

        OnBoardFormEmailField(),
        SizedBox(height: 15),

        //Selection dropdown for Gender

        OnBoardFormGenderField(),
        SizedBox(height: 15),

        //Selection dropdown for Age

        OnBoardAgeSelector(),
        SizedBox(height: 15),

        //Selection dropdown for Hight

        OnBoardHeightSelector(),
        SizedBox(height: 15),

        //Selection dropdown for Kgs and Lbs

        OnBoardWeightSelector(),
        SizedBox(height: 15),

        //Selection dropdown for Location

        OnBoardFormLocation(),
        SizedBox(height: 40),

        //Button to submit the form
        //Continue button for next page

        OnBoardFormButton(),
          ],
         ),
       ),
    );
   }
  }
```

And these are the separate widgets

```
 class _OnBoardAgeSelectorState extends State<OnBoardAgeSelector> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // age declarations
  var _selectedIndexForAge = "Age";
  var age = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 18; i <= 120; i++) {
      age.add(i);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          'AGE',
          style: TextConstants.feildHeadText,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 2,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 51,
          child: OutlineButton(
            
            shape: const StadiumBorder(),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
            highlightedBorderColor: Colors.grey,
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.grey.shade500,
              width: 1,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              // if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
              //   const Text(
              //     "Please select Age",
              //     style: TextStyle(
              //       color: Colors.red,
              //       fontSize: 16,
              //     ),
              //   );
              // }
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    child: CupertinoPicker(
                      itemExtent: 32,
                      onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            _selectedIndexForAge = age[index].toString();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      children: List<Widget>.generate(
                        age.length,
                        (int index) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text(age[index].toString()),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/dropdown.svg'),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    _selectedIndexForAge.toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    style: TextConstants.fieldPlaceholderText,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    }
  }
```

and so on and other widgets

when i am trying to validate it shows error like this

[image]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Not quite understand your question

Comment: sure just few minutes please

Comment: please check it now @s.am.i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a button inside the form to check the validation.

> You need to wrap them in scaffold first

> You can use _formKey.currentState!.validate()

To validate all the saperate widgets which are defined in saperate files like "Textformfield" and all...

But all the saperate widgets should come under the form widget and have a for key.

**Code (Your updated code)**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackexample/onbordname.dart';

class OnBoardForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OnBoardFormState createState() => _OnBoardFormState();
}

class _OnBoardFormState extends State<OnBoardForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              //Selection dropdown for first and Last Name

              OnBoardFormName(),
              SizedBox(height: 15),

              //Selection dropdown for Email
              OnBoardFormName(),
              // OnBoardFormEmailField(),
              SizedBox(height: 15),

              //Selection dropdown for Gender
              OnBoardFormName(),
              // OnBoardFormGenderField(),
              SizedBox(height: 15),

              //Selection dropdown for Age

              // OnBoardAgeSelector(),
              SizedBox(height: 15),

              //Selection dropdown for Hight

              // OnBoardHeightSelector(),
              SizedBox(height: 15),

              //Selection dropdown for Kgs and Lbs

              // OnBoardWeightSelector(),
              SizedBox(height: 15),

              //Selection dropdown for Location

              // OnBoardFormLocation(),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Good to go...')),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ),

              //Button to submit the form
              //Continue button for next page

              // OnBoardFormButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**TextField**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OnBoardFormName extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardFormName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OnBoardFormNameState createState() => _OnBoardFormNameState();
}

class _OnBoardFormNameState extends State<OnBoardFormName> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        const Text(
          'FIRST NAME',
          // style: TextConstants.feildHeadText,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 2,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          // style: TextConstants.fieldPlaceholderText,
          maxLength: 30,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
          autofocus: false,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            counterText: "",
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 10.0),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Color(0xffE3E5F6),
                width: 1,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
            ),
            hintText: 'First Name',
          ),
          validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please enter first name';
            }
            return value.length < 3
                ? 'Name must be at least 3 to 30 characters long'
                : null;
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Output**

*Validation working when charecter less than 3*

[image]

*Validation true*

[image]

**Update**

*You can't put the button in a new file, Because you can't access the state of that form key*

> If you strictly want to put the button on other file you need to pass the form key to the new screen ( or file ). or use a state management library like ' Bloc or Provider '

But for now i prefer to put the button on the same file.

Thank you

Comment: its working for text field but how can i do it for outline button ? its giving same error as above said

Comment: you cannot use button on another file. it's "STATE" should be inside the same file or if you strictly want the button to bo ont the next file you need to pass the form key to the next file or use any state management library like "BLOC,Provider,Getx... etc". But for now i think it's better to put the form key inside the form file itself

Answer (score 0):

```
final form = _formKey.currentState;
if (form.validate()){
   form.save();
}
```

This should be inside Form, form should have _formkey, furthermore you can use autovalidation mode. I think problem is your form.validate() is not inside Form.

Comment: oh ok got it, i thought we can call in different file, thanks for the answer

Comment: If it was help full make it acceptable answer.

Comment: its working for text field but how can i do it for outline button ? its giving same error as above said and i need to display error for each field

Comment: U mean validate from outline button ? or validate outline button

Comment: validate outline button

Comment: That you have to do in custom way, use a variable and make style changes